# Pytorch CNN - no improvement in accuracy during training

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I've built a CNN using Pytorch and am attempting to train it to classify dog and cat images from [this Kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/data).
The training loss starts at ~9 after the first epoch and then gets stuck at ~0.69 from the second epoch onwards. The testing loss and the accuracy are stack at ~0.69 and ~50% throughout the training.

At the moment my parameters are as follows:

- batch_size = 128
- num_epochs = 10
- learning_rate = 0.1
- criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
- optimizer = torch.optim.Adamax(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

I've tried changing the batch size, the optimizer and the learning rate. I've attached my code for creating the dataset and the CNN, and the training loop below.

### Definition of dataset class and transforms for augmentations

```
class CatDogDataset(Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, images_list, mode="train", transform=None):
        self.images_list = images_list
        self.mode = mode
        self.transform = transform
        
    # dataset length
    def __len__(self):
        self.dataset_len = len(self.images_list)
        return self.dataset_len
    
    # load an image
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image_name = self.images_list[idx]
        image = Image.open(image_name)
        image = image.resize((224,224)) # this is important when feeding into a pretrained model
        transformed_image = self.transform(image)
        image_category = image_name.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
        
        if self.mode == "train" or self.mode == "val":
            if image_category == "cat":
                label = 0 
            else:
                label = 1              
            return transformed_image, label
        else:
            return transformed_image

train_transforms = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5), 
        transforms.RandomRotation(15),
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224, scale=(0.8,1.0),ratio=(1.0,1.0)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize((0, 0, 0),(1, 1, 1))
    ])

val_transforms = transforms.Compose([ 
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize((0, 0, 0),(1, 1, 1))
    ])
```

### CNN class definition

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.cnn_layers = nn.Sequential(
            # convolutional layer 1
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=16, kernel_size=5, padding=0, stride=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2), 
            
            # convolutional layer 2
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=5, padding=0, stride=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2), 
            
            # convolutional layer 3
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5, padding=0, stride=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2) 
        )
        
        self.linear_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=64 * 24 * 24, out_features=10),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.3),
            nn.Linear(in_features=10, out_features=2)
        )
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.cnn_layers(x)
        #print(out.shape)
        out = out.view(-1, 64 * 24 * 24) # flatten 
        out = self.linear_layers(out)
        return out
```

### Model training and validation

```
from tqdm import tqdm

train_losses = []
val_losses = []
accuracy_list = []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    
    # perform training on train set
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0
    
    for images, labels in tqdm(train_dataloader):
        
        # load to gpu
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        
        # forward pass
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        running_loss += loss.item()
        
        # backprop and update model params
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
    # calculate training loss for the epoch
    train_losses.append(running_loss / len(train_dataloader))
    
    # calculate loss accuracy on validation set
    model.eval()
    running_loss = 0
    num_correct = 0
    num_predictions = 0
    
    with torch.no_grad():  
        for images, labels in tqdm(val_dataloader):
            
            # load to gpu
            images = images.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)
            
            # forward pass
            outputs = model(images)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            running_loss += loss.item()
            
            # calculate accuracy for batch
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            num_correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
            num_predictions += labels.size(0)
            
    # calculate val loss for epoch
    val_losses.append(running_loss / len(val_dataloader))
    
    # calculate accuracy for epoch
    accuracy = num_correct / num_predictions * 100
    accuracy_list.append(accuracy)
    
    print("[Epoch: %d / %d],  [Train loss: %.4f],  [Test loss: %.4f],  [Acc: %.2f]" \
          %(epoch+1, num_epochs, train_losses[-1], val_losses[-1], accuracy))
```

Comment: Try to increase the penultimate `Linear` layer neurons from 10 to, say, 1024, and keep using `BatchNorm` instead of `Dropout`.

Comment: Thanks @aretor, the accuracy improved to 72%! Do you have any explanation why this helped?

Comment: In short, you were squashing your input features, with size 64 x 24 x 24 = 36864, to a "tiny" embedding space of dimension 10. By doing so, you lose too much information and the network is not able to discriminate. Have a look at some common CNN and check their linear layer sizes!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I'll take a look :)